# Looping if statement in Lua

Tags: loops, if-statement, lua

I'm having some trouble looping a piece of code.

I made a program where you have to insert a number and the PC computes some stuff.

My problem is that I'm not able to loop the if statement that prevents the user from typing a letter or something like that.

Here's the piece of code I need to loop:

```
-- first number
io.write("Tell me a number: ")
a = io.read("*number")
-- typing a letter
if a == nil
    then
        io.write("\n", "Sorry, this is an invalid imput.", "\n")
        io.write("\n", "Please tell me a number: ")
end
```

Could you please help me?

I've just started programming in Lua and I'm quite confused.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a... ...well, **loop:**

```
local l = io.read("*line")
local a = tonumber(l)

while a == nil do
    print("sorry, invalid input")
    l = io.read("*line")
    a = tonumber(l)
end
```

(Side note: I don't speak lua, I've found the `tonumber()` function after 2 minutes of googling.)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Actually, I've just started programming... from scratch.

Thank you again and have a good day. :)

Comment: As a side note @H2CO3 solution teaches you one more thing: when getting input from a user interactively you should read the input always as text (`io.read("*line")`), then process it to see if it matches your expectations and issue errors accordingly. `io.read("*number")` is used essentially when reading from files with known structure, i.e. when you know you will get a number. For this reason `io.read("*number")` is seldom used, since it reads from the standard input, which is usually the console unless some redirection at OS level has taken place.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Exactly. I've tried the above code with `io.read("*number")` but it didn't work. I assume that if it fails, it doesn't consume the characters to be read. Is that right?

Comment: @H2CO3 it uses `fscanf` with a default format of "%lf" internally, see [`read_number` function](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/liolib.c.html#read_number) in the sources. Thus it has the same behavior as `fscanf` if a matching failure happens.